# error in the concatenation of multiple message contents omnet++

Tags: omnet++

I have this code where I take the message from handle message from both process blocks (Hey.cc and See.cc) and combine it into a new message (in There.cc) but it doesn't seem to work please help

Hey.cc

```
#include "Hey.h"

Define_Module(Hey);

void Hey::initialize()
{
    // TODO - Generated method body
    cMessage *mmsg = new cMessage("hello");
    send(mmsg,"hello");
}

void Hey::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    // TODO - Generated method body
}
```

and See.cc

```
#include "See.h"

Define_Module(See);

void See::initialize()
{
    // TODO - Generated method body
    cMessage *smsg = new cMessage("hi");
    send(smsg,"tempexit");
}

void See::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    // TODO - Generated method body
}
```

and There.cc

```
#include "There.h"
#include "See.h"
#include "Hey.h"
#include <string>

Define_Module(There);

void There::initialize()
{
    // TODO - Generated method body
}

void There::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    cMessage *smsg = new cMessage("hi");    // supposed to be from See.cc
    cMessage *mmsg = new cMessage("hello"); // supposed to be from Hey.cc
    cMessage strNew = *smsg;
    cMessage sstrNew = *mmsg;
    cMessage rNew = strNew + sstrNew ;

    EV << rNew ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The second argument of `send` method should be [the name of gate](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:sending-messages) or a pointer to `cGate` object. Does `Hey.ned` contain `hello` output gate, and `See.ned` contain `tempexit` gate?
2. Class `cMessage` doesn't have `operator+` so one **cannot** add two instances of `cMessage`. By the way: what do you expect as a result of this operation? If encapsulation messages, you should use [encapsulate()](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:messages:encapsulating-packets).